# how to stop activityIndicator only when webView content is completely loaded

Tags: iphone, ios, uiwebview, loading, activity-indicator

I created an webView-based application. I'm using an activityIndicator; its animation begins at `webViewDidStartLoad`, and finishes at `webViewDidFinishLoad`.

The problem is that the activityIndicator is stopped, but my webView content is not completely loaded.

How can I fix it? How can I stop the ActivityIndicator only when ALL content of my webView is shown?

Comment: UIWebView is a subclass of UIView, perhaps you should stop the animation indicator in the viewDidAppear method?

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the activity indicator in this delegate: **webViewDidFinishLoad**

[image]